# Autocomplete show all values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have a struggle showing all possible autocomplete rows.
I`m using db to store all the rows.
Now I use that script :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#Industry").autocomplete({
             source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/Employee/SuggestWorkExperienceIndustry",
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: { Prefix: request.term },
                     success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data, function (item) {
                             return { label: item.Industry, value: item.Industry };
                         }))

                     }
                 })
             },
             messages: {
                 noResults: "failure", results: ""
             }
         });
     });
</script>
```

Controller part :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SuggestWorkExperienceIndustry(string Prefix)
    {
        using (var db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            var industryList = db.WorkExperienceIndustries.ToList();

            var industry = (from n in industryList
                              where n.Industry.ToLower().Contains(Prefix.ToLower())
                              select new { n.Industry });

            return Json(industry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

It works well, but i cant get the idea how to get all the rows from the db when user clicks on field.

Comment: Does the request happen when user click on field? If so, what is the value of the `Prefix`?

Comment: @Andrei nope, request does not happen. If only it happened i d check if `Prefix` is `null` and set all values from db to `industry`, and that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it faster for those who had the same question.
The final script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#VarName").autocomplete({

             source: function (request, response) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: "json",
                     data: { Prefix: request.term },

                     success: function (data) {
                         response($.map(data, function (item) {
                             return { label: item.VarName, value: item.VarName};
                         }))

                     }
                 })
             },
             messages: {
                 noResults: "failure", results: ""
             },
             minLength: 0,
         }).focus(function () {
             $(this).autocomplete("search")});
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [property](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength) in autocomplete widget `minLength`, which has a default set at `1`. Which means you need to enter at least one character in the textbox before it starts requesting for data. Set it to `0` and it should load the whole list right away:

```
minLength: 0
```

But be very sure this is the behavior you really want, because it will indeed load all your items. Might not be very user friendly.

**Update.** It seems there is no built-in way to trigger search just on focus though. But it is really simple to trigger it manually:

```
$("#Industry").autocomplete({
    source: ...
    messages: ...
    minLength: 0
}).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Andrei, it partly resolved my problem. Now the full list is uploaded, but not immediately on click, i have to input smtng and delete it so as to send request with 0 lenght. Is it possible to make on click without additional actions?

Comment: @GeekyNuns, partly? What's the other part?

Comment: Just pressed enter, so the comment was uncompleted.

Comment: @GeekyNuns, I see. Updated